# VC++ preprocessor parameters-count limit

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, c-preprocessor

What is the VC++ preprocessor parameters-count limit? I'm using VS2013

I only found doc. for Linux: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-limits.html

Comment: Searching for `vc++ compiler limits` gave me [this link as its first hit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft39hh4x.aspx). Whatever limits isn't mentioned there can be found in [the standard](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I searched for preprocessor limits, not compilation limits. I guess that microsoft isn't good even in documentation... about the standard - Microsoft neglects it many times; one can't count on it

Comment: Please go to the link, the information is right there on that page. Also note that compiler and preprocessor haven't been separate in a long time, preprocessing and compilation is just [different phases of the same process](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases).

Comment: I saw it in Martin Bonner answer. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft39hh4x.aspx says the maximumm number of parameters in one macro definition is 127.